# Are MySQL Update Statements Too Expensive?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, scalability, amazon-rds

I've been reading as much as I can about how to write a scalable MySQL schema but I'm still not sure if this is a good idea.

For what it's worth, I'm hosting this project on EC2 with RDS.

In my database, I have a core table that is going to be more writes than reads (Approximately 70% writes and 30% reads I'd guess).

However, when I create new rows in the table, I'm going to need to add updates to it every 5 seconds or so. On the whole, since multiple rows are going to be added/updated every second that means **an UPDATE statement is executing every second or so**.

From based on what I've been reading, MySQL has something called Table Locking that happens when you are writing to a table? Since this table is also going to be being read from significantly, would it cause too much overhead/locking to use UPDATE statements on the rows?

My options (as far as I know) are:

1. Do UPDATE statements on a large table on a frequent basis (every second or maybe more)
2. Have a staging table where I create rows, update them, and when ready (about 20 mins until the row is finalized), ship the row from staging table to main table.

I want to avoid the staging table because it makes my users wait about 20 minutes before they can see content, but I'm wondering if it's a necessary evil or not.

Any other ideas? Suggestions?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Whether table locks are applied or not depends on the storage engine. MyISAM does table locks, InnoDB does row locks.

As you want to read **and** write rows, you will have to use InnoDB is it will allow concurrent access to each row (readers don't block writers, writers don't block readers)

If you udpate the rows based on the primary key, they should be fairly fast (if your server can keep up with the IO that is beeing generated by this).

Comment: I am indeed updating the rows based on primary key. I hadn't decided on a storage engine yet, but I've heard that InnoDB isn't very fast in most cases? But in my case as you point out InnoDB seems to be the better solution because I don't want to lock up the entire table, just a specific row.

Comment: @user Most applications are about 90-95% read with very few writes, and that's where MyISAM is considered slightly faster.  InnoDB has better data integrity to ensure data doesn't get corrupted (most notably MyISAM does not support transactions).  In this case the table-locking of MyISAM will almost certainly make it slower as it's intended for high read low write scenarios.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @user59% - you'd better check your sources, better still check my profile and look at all the performance related questions i answer i.e. ques. please help, my myisam system sucks... ans. use innodb !

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of whether Update statements are expensive, it looks like you are going to need to do them anyway. If you had the option of not updating the table, clearly that would be more performant, but I assume that is not the case.

The real question you seem to be asking seems to be more about concurrency than performance anyway. Specifically, you seem to be asking whether you get better concurrency with lots of small updates or fewer batch updates each containing the same total number of changes.

In my experience you are much better off doing a lot of small updates rather than batching them for purposes of concurrency. However, you will generally have better performance (for the updates) if you batch them up.

Another thing to understand is that there are multiple types of locks. The locks on the table for updates and selects are not the same, and there are also considerations about whether your statements lock just a row, page or the entire table. Usually locks are fairly localized, but for this type of application you will want to read up on the specifics of locking strategies and how to manipulate them to your specific needs.

Comment: Hmm. So it's fine to do very frequent updates on an InnoDB table? As long as it won't hold up the SELECTs that should work out

Comment: It is very hard to make such a general statement. As is almost always the case you need to test it under the likely conditions your app will run under. The main point of my advice is to read up on Locking for whichever DB engine you use. It is a tricky subject and can have major ramifications if you do it wrong.